# Retrieve and group by object element in JS (JSON)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a file versions.json:

```
{
    "components":{
    "toto": {
        "artifacts": [
        {
            "name": "test-toto",
            "type": "html"
        },
        {
            "name": "test-tata",
            "type": "html"
        }
        ]
    },
    "titi": {
        "test": [
        {
            "name": "test-titi",
            "type": "html"
        }
        ]
    }
    "versions": {
    "test-toto": "2.1",
    "test-tata": "2.2",
    "test-titi": "2.3"
    }
```

I've got a file versions2.json:

```
{
    "components":{
    "toto": {
        "artifacts": [
        {
            "name": "test-toto",
            "type": "html"
        },
        {
            "name": "test-tata",
            "type": "html"
        }
        ]
    },
    "titi": {
        "test": [
        {
            "name": "test-titi",
            "type": "html"
        }
        ]
    }
    "versions": {
    "test-toto": "1.0",
    "test-tata": "1.1",
    "test-titi": "1.3"
    }
```

I want to push only the versions (bigger and smaller versions) where the version is different with their name of component

Expected:

```
[{
    components: "toto",
    newVersion: "2.2",   // bigger version (here test-tata) 
    oldVersion: "1.0"    // smaller version (here toto-tata)
},
{
    components: "titi",
    newVersion: "2.3",
    oldVersion: "1.3",
}
]
```

Actual Result:

```
[{
    components: "toto",
    newVersion: "2.1", 
    oldVersion: "1.0"    
},
{
    components: "toto",
    newVersion: "2.2", 
    oldVersion: "1.1"    
},
{
    components: "titi",
    newVersion: "2.3",
    oldVersion: "1.3",
}
]
```

My script :

```
public async listDiffer(): Promise<any[]> {
        const showVersion = fs.readFileSync("versions.json", "utf8");
        const json1 = JSON.parse(showVersion);
        const list1 = json1.versions;
        const components = json1.components;

        const showVersion2 = fs.readFileSync("versions2.json", "utf8");
        const json2 = JSON.parse(showVersion2);
        const list2 = json2.versions;

        const diffList: Array<{ components: string; newVersion: string; oldVersion: string }> = [];

        const keysFromHead = Object.keys(list1);
        const keysFromHeadComponents = Object.keys(components);

        keysFromHeadComponents.forEach((element) => {
            components[element].artifacts.map((arti) => {
                keysFromHead.forEach((key) => {
                    if (list1[key] !== list2[key] && key === arti.name) {
                        diffList.push({
                            components: element,
                            newVersion: list1[key],
                            oldVersion: list2[key],
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        console.log(diffList);
        return diffList;
    }
```

So what I want it's if they are multiple element in same components, I just need to retrieve the smaller and bigger version (like toto example)

Thanks in  advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

By assuming `components` is in the first level of the object, you could take both objects in an object and create an object for collecting the versions. Then get the value as result.

```js
const
    version1 = { components: { toto: { artifacts: [{ name: "test-toto", type: "html" }, { name: "test-tata", type: "html" }] }, titi: { test: [{ name: "test-titi", type: "html" }] } }, versions: { "test-toto": "2.1", "test-tata": "2.2", "test-titi": "2.3" } },
    version2 = { components: { toto: { artifacts: [{ name: "test-toto", type: "html" }, { name: "test-tata", type: "html" }] }, titi: { test: [{ name: "test-titi", type: "html" }] } }, versions: { "test-toto": "1.0", "test-tata": "1.1", "test-titi": "1.3" } },
    result = Object.values([version1, version2].reduce((r, { components, versions }) => {
        Object.keys(components).forEach(components => {
            const version = versions['test-' + components];
            if (!r[components]) {
                r[components] = { components, oldVersion: version, newVersion: version };
                return;
            }
            if (version.localeCompare(r[components].oldVersion, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }) < 0) {
                r[components].oldVersion = version;
            }
            if (version.localeCompare(r[components].newVersion, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }) > 0) {
                r[components].newVersion = version;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The componetns "tata" doesn't exists. In my case, I've got only 2 components so the output need to be with 2 components and not 3 ...

Comment: test-tata got the bigger version in components toto so in "newVersion" I need to put this version (2.2) and not (2.1)

Comment: where does `test-tata` belong to?